# Color change by clicking object instead of drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I had followed [the "Create HTML5 Canvas Drawing Board Within 5 Minutes!" tutorial](http://www.onlywebpro.com/2013/01/10/create-html5-canvas-drawing-board-within-5-minutes) a few days ago and now I want to change the color by clicking on a colourd object.

http://bit.ly/18Gxu9h

How can I get rid of the `<ul>` selection's, and choose a color by clicking on them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you click on the div, grab the id (for seemless integration, name each id the color you want and simply apply it (you'll have to modify every instance though)), and set it to the canvas drawing color. If you use the IDs you have now, you'll have several if statements to write

Comment: Off-topic as per:  _"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — **in the question itself**. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org) for guidance."_

Comment: Check out this fiddle. Answer pasted below. http://jsfiddle.net/Tnm4t/

Comment: @Sparky where are you on the other 4 bajillion questions the I comment. "Code. We need code!!!" Lol

Comment: @Jack, earn more rep so you can vote to close... comments are not mandatory.

Comment: @Sparky I'm trying to earn more rep. I'm relatively new to the community :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have duplicate IDs, that you cannot have, it's invalid HTML.

My suggestion:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="board">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024px" height="500px"></canvas>
        <p>Kies een kleur:
            <select id="selectColorSel">
                <option data-id="colBlack" value="#000000" selected="selected">Zwart</option>
                <option data-id="colRed" value="#be1e28">Rood</option>
                <option data-id="colBlue" value="#479abd">Blauw</option>
                <option data-id="colGreen" value="#3bab4b">Groen</option>
                <option data-id="colOrange" value="#f3601b">Oranje</option>
                <option data-id="colYellow" value="#f6c910">Geel</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- END board -->
    <div id="selectColorDiv">
        <div id="colBlue"></div>
        <div id="colRed"></div>
        <div id="colYellow"></div>
        <div id="colGreen"></div>
        <div id="colBlack"></div>
        <div id="colRed"></div>
        <div id="colYellow"></div>
        <div id="colGreen"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
window.onload = function () {
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var curColor = $('#selectColorSel option:selected').val();
    if (myCanvas) {
        var isDown = false;
        var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
        var canvasX, canvasY;
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        $(myCanvas)
            .mousedown(function (e) {
            isDown = true;
            ctx.beginPath();
            canvasX = e.pageX - myCanvas.offsetLeft;
            canvasY = e.pageY - myCanvas.offsetTop;
            ctx.moveTo(canvasX, canvasY);
        })
            .mousemove(function (e) {
            if (isDown != false) {
                canvasX = e.pageX - myCanvas.offsetLeft;
                canvasY = e.pageY - myCanvas.offsetTop;
                ctx.lineTo(canvasX, canvasY);
                ctx.strokeStyle = curColor;
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        })
            .mouseup(function (e) {
            isDown = false;
            ctx.closePath();
        });
    }
    $('#selectColorSel').change(function () {
        curColor = $('#selectColorSel option:selected').val();
    });
    $('#selectColorDiv div').click(function () {
        var sel = $('[data-id="' + this.id + '"]').val();
        $('#selectColorSel').val(sel);
         curColor = $('#selectColorSel option:selected').val();
    });
};
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bsPUt/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot. The UL sections change when I click on a color, but the color stays the same.

Comment: @YouGo, yes, i fixed that now. http://jsfiddle.net/bsPUt/1/

Comment: Haha, you're a boss! Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: good one dude... and you helped a person to complete his assignment.

Comment: @vishalkin, we're all here to help!

Comment: @Sergio but it looks good if a questioner has its own code or knows the code but having little difficulty in that.. but anyways i appreciate your work.. this is one of the best answer i have seen till now..

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Tnm4t/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
       var color = document.getElementById('selectColor').value;

        document.getElementById('colBlack').style.display = "none";    
        document.getElementById('colBlue').style.display = "none";    
        document.getElementById('colRed').style.display = "none";    
        document.getElementById('colGreen').style.display = "none";    
        document.getElementById('colOrange').style.display = "none";    
        document.getElementById('colYellow').style.display = "none";

        document.getElementById(color).style.display = "block";

    }
</script>

<p>Kies een kleur:<select id="selectColor" onchange="myFunction()">
                      <option value="colBlack" selected="selected">Zwart</option>
                      <option value="colRed">Rood</option>
                      <option value="colBlue">Blauw</option>
                      <option value="colGreen">Groen</option>
                      <option value="colOrange">Oranje</option>
                      <option value="colYellow">Geel</option>
                      </select>
    </p>
<div id="selectedColor">
        <div id="colBlue"></div>
        <div id="colRed"></div>
        <div id="colYellow"></div>
        <div id="colOrange"></div>
        <div id="colGreen"></div>       
        <div id="colBlack"></div>           
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#selectedColor div{
    display:none;
}
#colBlack {background-color:#000; height:100px; width:128px; float:left;}
#colRed {background-color:#be1e28; height:100px; width:128px; float:left;}
#colBlue {background-color:#479abd; height:100px; width:128px; float:left;}
#colYellow {background-color:#f6c910; height:100px; width:128px; float:left;}
#colGreen {background-color:#3bab4b; height:100px; width:128px; float:left;}
#colOrange {background-color:#ffa500; height:100px; width:128px; float:left;}
```

Misread OP question, editing fiddle.

Comment: OP has a `<canvas>` that should be connected to the select. This code has also duplicate ID's

Comment: @Sergio, there is not duplicate IDs. I misread his question regardless, I thought he was wanting to hide the boxes. I'll fix my answer, but read my answer again before I edit it and tell me if you see any duplicate IDs.

Comment: true! No duplicate ID's I was the fast one reading now.

Comment: If you downvoted me, please remove. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, appreciate it. I'm updating my answer now, fyi.

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the UL section out of view? Like a hide or something? Thanks so far!

Comment: Isn't the answer above correct? The one @Sergio posted?

Comment: Yea, its correct, but I still have the selector in view. When I filter it, the color is still black.

Comment: In the CSS add `display:none` to the id of the select tag. http://jsfiddle.net/bsPUt/2/

Comment: @YouGo, if the answer was not complete don't accept it. What you mean by "when I filter the selector" ?

Comment: @Sergio he wanted the dropdown gone.

Comment: Thanks, display:none works, super!